# Unity3D: Disable player input but not character movement?

Tags: unity

I'm trying to code a dash/air dash for a 2D platformer. In my character controller's `FixedUpdate()`, I have various `if` statements that cause certain actions when a button is pressed.

To disable player input while the dash was happening, I tried putting `Dash()` in an `IEnumerator` with a simple test code like this:

```
IEnumerator Dash() {
    if (player.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0)
        {
            thePlayer.GetComponent<HeroController>().enabled = false;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
            move = move * 2;
            thePlayer.GetComponent<HeroController>().enabled = true;
    }
}
```

But since the character's physics are inside the character controller, both the player's input and the character's movements are stopped when the controller is disabled. How can I disable inputs while still allowing the character to dash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a bool that, if true, checks for all input. If false, you essentially turn off all input.

```js
bool DoInputs = true;
IEnumerator Dash() {
  if (DoInputs)
    if (player.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0)
        {
            thePlayer.GetComponent<HeroController>().enabled = false;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
            move = move * 2;
            thePlayer.GetComponent<HeroController>().enabled = true;
    }
}
```

If you'd like to keep detecting the axis, simply store it in a variable and set this variable to the input only if the bool is true.

```js
    bool DoInputs = true;
    float AxisH;
    IEnumerator Dash() {
      if (DoInputs)
              AxisH = player.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        if (AxisH < 0)
            {
                thePlayer.GetComponent<HeroController>().enabled = false;
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
                move = move * 2;
                thePlayer.GetComponent<HeroController>().enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

That will keep the character moving while not affecting it with input. Hope one of these suits your style. Cheers.